# Ability to add, remove and modify fields - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, nosql

I am building a ERP kinda software where there are many defined entities. These entities have several attribute models. I want the users to be able to add/edit/remove attributes to these models.

Basically is there a good way to allow users edit database fields? I think we will be needing a relational database as a base. So would mixing nosql and rdbms be ok?

Is there any other way to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom attributes for that like create a table named as table_name and the structure of the table will be something like this

```
user_id attribute_name attribute_value
```

now user can add as much attributes as he/she want and on the basis of user_id all the attributes can be fetched!

Comment: is there a different way. This seems to be the st forward way to do this.